# Wrapping Native Async functions with Task<T>

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, pinvoke, native, async-await

I'm attempting to write a c# wrapper around a third-party library written in native code for consumption in our apps, which are almost exclusively written in .NET, and I'm trying to remain faithful to the C# patterns.  Almost all the calls in this library are asynchronous in nature, and it would seem appropriate to wrap all my async calls into Task<T> objects.  Here's an oversimplified example of how the native library is structured:

```
delegate void MyCallback(string outputData);

class MyNativeLibrary
{
    public int RegisterCallback(MyCallback callback); // returns -1 on error
    public int RequestData(string inputData);         // returns -1 on error
}
```

Right now, I've provided my return values through event subscription, however I believe this would be a far better way to return my data:

```
class WrapperAroundNativeCode
{
    public async Task<string> RequestData(string inputData);
}
```

So far I've been unsuccessful in finding an appropriate way to implement this, and I'm reaching out to folks with more experience in working with Task<T> objects and the async/await pattern than I do.

Comment: How do you know which `RequestData` caused the `MyCallback` request?

Comment: And how do you get notified of exceptions?

Comment: And how do you unregister the callback? Or does it unregister itself automatically?

Comment: @luiscubal, There's actually a couple of ways to register callbacks to this 3rd-party lib.  It only took me a couple of years of working here to master the techniques!

Comment: @StephenCleary, Errors usually come from the integer return values.  I had been interpreting the error code into a .NET exception and passing it as part of the result event.  With `TaskCompletionSource`, I'll just use the `.SetException()` method instead.

Comment: @svick, I've been registering the callback on the start of the app, and keep it for the lifetime of the application.  As is the case with most developers, they don't document very well, and they don't discuss the best way to unregister.  I would assume passing `NULL` to the register callback method, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @JoeyHerrington: My point is there's no way to detect an asynchronous error. I.e., you register your callback fine, and your request goes through fine, but there's some error in processing the request; there's no way for you to be notified of that.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I believe I understand what you mean, but let me know if I get it wrong.  The 3rd-party lib I'm working with does a pretty good job conveying error information (I.E. poorly formatted string, etc) through the callback, and I just bubbled the exception to the event I wrote.  That's what I meant by invoking `.SetException()` of `TaskCompletionSource` instead.  By the way, I really appreciate the contributions you've made to the Async libraries.  Big fan!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx). You'd wrap your library by creating a `TaskCompletionSource`, creating an instance of `MyNativeLibrary` and registering a callback which set the result of the task completion source, and then requesting data from same instance. If either of these steps fails, set an error on the task completion source. Then just return the value of the [`TaskCompletionSource<>.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449187.aspx) property to the caller.

(This is assuming you can create separate instances of `MyNativeLibrary` - if you can only create a *single* instance across your whole app, it gets a lot harder.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  I have one question left:  `Task` has a generic and non-generic flavor, but I only saw a generic version of `TaskCompletionSource`.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @JoeyHerrington `Task<T>` extends `Task`, so there's an implicit cast from `Task<T>` to `Task`. You can just build a `TaskCompletionSource<object>` and use `SetResult(null);` (or any dummy value instead of `null`).

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I did.  I just didn't know if there was an actual non-generic type.

Answer (score 12):

You would use a [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) for this. Something along the lines of the following code:

```
class WrapperAroundNativeCode
{
    public async Task<string> RequestData(string inputData)
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var result = Native.RegisterCallback(s => completionSource.SetResult(s));
        if(result == -1)
        {
            completionSource.SetException(new SomeException("Failed to set callback"));
            return completionSource.Task;
        }

        result = Native.RequestData(inputData);
        if(result == -1)
            completionSource.SetException(new SomeException("Failed to request data"));
        return completionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

This answer assumes that there won't be concurrent calls to this method. If there were you would need some way to differentiate between the different calls. Many APIs provide a `userData` payload that you can set to a unique value per call, so that you can differentiate.

Comment: Looks like you nailed it!  I tried this technique, and it seemed to work quite well.  Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry, I could only mark one answer as correct otherwise, I'd mark both you and Jon Skeet as correct.